# Counting orders per hour in a month defined by WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, hour

I'm hoping to count orders per hour for every day in the last month.

I have this `WHERE` clause from another report (1), which determines the correct month 'last month' from the point it is run.

I'd like to ideally have hours as my 'leftmost' column, rather than the date.

I thought I could get distinct days within the `WHERE` and then count datepart where hour = 1, 2 etc. However, this code below (2) leads to over 300 records.

(1)

```
WHERE YEAR(Bookings.PICKUP_DATE) 
        = YEAR(DATEADD(mm, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, getdate()), 0)))
  AND MONTH(Bookings.PICKUP_DATE) 
        = MONTH(DATEADD(mm, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, getdate()), 0)))
```

(2)

```
select 
   distinct(datepart(dd,b.pickup_date)) as DAYOFTHEMONTH
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH,B.PICKUP_DATE) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the average count per hour for each day? or the count for a particular hour for each day? or something else? You should define your table definitions, and perhaps show what sample output might look like.

Comment: Apologies. I have a bookings table and a column within called pickup_date. I am aiming to have a 24 x 31 (or 31 x 24) table with the number of occurrences of pickup_date for each hour of each day.

Comment: I have managed to solve this. It was a case of adding DAY function to my GROUP BY. I have a full reply with correct code descibingg how I solved this issue. I'll post as soon as I get 10 rep, or more likely, after 6 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for not being clear before. I've worked this out now.

The reason I had too many records was simply that my GROUP BY clause did not have the DAY function applied.

My dataset is now correct and I get all days in the date range with:

```
distinct(datepart(dd,timestamp)) as DAYOFTHEMONTH
```

The count of orders for an hour (In this case midnight) is:

```
count(case when datepart(hh,timestamp) = 0 then timestamp else null end) as '00:00'
```

My WHERE clause is giving all data for the month before the present one:

```
WHERE
YEAR(timestamp) = YEAR(DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate()),0)))
AND
MONTH(timestamp) = MONTH(DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate()),0)))
```

Lastly, I get the correct grouping with DAY applied to the GROUP BY

```
GROUP BY day(timestamp)
```

Sorry to have been unclear. Hope this will prove useful to somebody out there in the future.

Thanks for the edit/help too guys, I'll ensure any other questions I ask are correct:)